# Unable to launch the UI Automator viewer

Tags: java, sdk, android-uiautomator

I am unable to launch the UI Automator viewer can anyone help me ?how can I launch it? when I double click on "uiautomatorviewer"  for some time black window  opens but closed automatically even I had set variables in windows path variable 
ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
even i am not sure how I can alaunch it?

Answer (score 2):

If your using JDK 9 or 10 Please downgrade it to JDK 8. It should solve the problem.

Also ensure you have set the below path's correctly.

ANDROID_HOME  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

JAVA_HOME     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

Under path in System variables

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

Comment: It is the way to get the job done, but it is not secure to downgrade java as it could affect other programs and it is not secure either

Comment: Found a solution which DON'T NEED ONE TO DOWNGRADE TO JAVA 8 so, there is option for JRE to run VM for "uiautomatorviewer".

One needs to install Android Studio and add the below location to "path" System Variable

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
I have jdk-11.0.6 and "uiautomatorviewer" is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Adding here as Answer so that It should be clear to everyone.

Found a solution which **DON'T NEED ONE TO DOWNGRADE TO JAVA 8**+
so, there is an option for JRE to run VM for "uiautomatorviewer".

Step:1
One needs to install Android Studio

Step:2
Add the below location to "path" System Variable-

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
```

I have jdk-11.0.6 and "uiautomatorviewer" is working fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075862/11802483 please check this comment