# Couldn't open uiautomatorviewer after setting PATH

Tags: python, appium, ui-automation

Today I followed the Youtube for setting my laptop(linux-Debian) to install
the android SDK tool , I have set PATH in environment variables via command line
[terminal line]：

```
hauying@hauying-yoga-linux:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/hauying/Android/tools:/home/hauying/Android/platform-tools
```

After setting the PATH successfully, I can't open "uiautomatorviewer".
It shows following error when I try to open it:
[terminal line]：

```
hauying@hauying-yoga-linux:~/Andriod/tools/bin$ '/home/hauying/Andriod/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer' 
-Djava.ext.dirs=/home/hauying/Andriod/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/hauying/Andriod/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried using command -classpath ,but it can't find this command.

How can I open my "uiautomatorviewer". Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the instructions on below websites. These might help resolve the issue:

1. https://sansatechnology.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/how-to-fix-appium-uiautomatorviewer-issue/
2. Workaround: https://discuss.appium.io/t/uiautomatorviewer-throws-error/11620/15

Comment: I have another question ,could you help me?

Comment: I would surely try my best. Please raise it as a separate question if it is not related to this question. The community is big and very helpful :)

Comment: DON'T NEED ONE TO DOWNGRADE TO JAVA 8 . Please refer to solution given by me on this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072271/unable-to-launch-the-ui-automator-viewer/73725475#73725475